# Retrieving values from a table in HTML using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i was just wondering whats the best way to retrieve the current values from this HTMl code using jquery and storing them in to a array?

```
<table id="metric_summary">
    <tbody>   
    <tr class="editable_metrics">
        <td><label>DataSet:</label></td>
       <td><input name="DataSet" value="prod"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="editable_metrics">
        <td><label>HostGroup:</label></td>
       <td><input name="HostGroup" value="MONITOR"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="editable_metrics">
        <td><label>Host:</label></td>
       <td><input name="Host" value="ALL"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="editable_metrics">
        <td><label>Class:</label></td>
       <td><input name="Class" value="CPU"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="editable_metrics">
        <td><label>Object:</label></td>
       <td><input name="Object" value="cpu"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="editable_metrics">
        <td><label>Metric:</label></td>
       <td><input name="Metric" value="CapacityCPUUtilization"></td>
    </tr>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test it, but it should do the job:

```
var Dict = {};
$('#metric_summary input').each(function (index, input) {
  Dict[input.name] = input.value;
});
```

**edit:** if you want to store the values in an array without the labels, you can do this:

```
var Values = [];
$('.editable_metrics input').each(function (i, input) {
  Values.push(input.value);
});
```

But you won't know which value refers to which label. You may want to do this instead:

```
var Values = [];
$('.editable_metrics input').each(function (i, input) {
  Values.push( [ input.label, input.value ] );
});
```

Comment: #metric_summary will give you the table, not the rows.

Comment: This fails for me. The first parameter of the function passed into `each()` is the index, http://api.jquery.com/each/ the second is the Element. So revise `(input)` to be `(index, input)` and the code will work.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. I wonder how useful is the index compared to the actual element.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i have decided im just going to stor the current value of the input box in to an array. 

would it be something like this:

'function retrieve_metric_stats(){
var metricVals = [];
    $('.editable_metric').each(function (input) {
    MetricVals = input.val;
 return metricVals;
}); 
}'

Answer (score 1):

I would iterate over each row, and the parse each for the `label` and `input value` I cared about. Note that in the event you have duplicate label names, the object storage will lose values.

```
var arr_storage = []; // var to store as array
var obj_storage = {}; // var to store as object
$('#metric_summary tr').each(function(){
    var key = $('td label:first', this).text()
    var value = $('td input:first', this).val();
    arr_storage.push([ key, value ]);
    obj_storage[key] = value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there are a couple of ways to do it. The basic steps:

1. Select all of the TDs.
2. Iterate through them, adding them to your Object.

There are a bunch of different ways to do that. None is really wrong or right, but some may perform better or worse than the others. If you'll need to access those rows or cells again, think of a way in which you can chain this with other operations on the site or how you can cache things for performance reasons.

Here's a way to get an array of label/value Objects using `map( )`, which [maps array-like structures to an array](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) and works well in situations like these:

```
someObject = $('#metric_summary .editable_metrics td:first-child').map(function(){
    var $el = $(this);
    return { 'label' : $el.find('label').html(), 'value' : $el.next().find('input').val() }
});
```

Probably not very efficient, but should get you started.